# $p$ prime and $d | (p-1)$ then the congruence $x^{d} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ has exactly $d$ incongruent solutions

Tags: number-theory, congruences

If $p$ prime and $d | (p-1)$ then the congruence $x^{d} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ has  exactly $d$  incongruent  solutions.

I have this hint: 
$x^{p-1}-1=(x^{d}-1)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $p-1-d$
We can use Lagrange theorem and Fermat Theorem

Comment: At most, how many solutions can the congruence $q(x)\equiv0\pmod{p}$ have?

Comment: By Fermat's Little theorem $x^{p-1}-1$ has exactly $p-1$ roots mod $p$. By Lagrange theorem $x^d-1$ has at most $d$ roots and $q(x)$ has at most $p-1-d$ roots and $(d)+(p-1-d)=p-1$, so $x^d-1$ must have exactly $d$ roots and, although it's not needed, $q(x)$ has exactly $p-1-d$ roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $d \mid p-1$, $x^d \mid x^{p-1}$ as polynomial, hence $x^d -1 \mid x^{p-1} -1$.

Suppose $p-1 = kd$, then $x^{p-1} -1 = x^{kd} - 1 = (x^d-1)(x^{(k-1)d}+...+1)$. Since $x^d-1$ is factored out, we have $x^d-1 \mid x^{kd}-1$, then $x^d-1 \mid x^{p-1} -1$, which implies $x^d-1 \mid x(x^{p-1} -1)$ so $x^d-1 \mid x^p-x$.

Next, we need a theorem saying that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has exactly $n$ distinct solutions if and only if $f(x) \mid x^p-p\pmod{p}$. For a proof of this theorem, please consult https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec7.pdf